# ffmpeg sequence start at 30 and adds 30 in each image name

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, mp4, frame-rate

I have a file with~ 11000 images and I want to make a video out of it. I generated these photos with a naming t_00030, t_00060, etc..
I am using this command in linux

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i t_%06d.png Uperturbations.mp4
```

and I have this error

> 'Could find no file with path 't_%06d.png' and index in the range 0-4
> t_%06d.png: No such file or directory'

Is there a way to do this from the command line,; should the naming be incremental of 1? Or is it another problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the `image2` muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1). There are `start_number` and `start_number_range` options which let you pick the first file, but not sure if your increment of 30 could be supported. Another option is to see if `-pattern glob` works on your system and if so use it.

Comment: I had to generate the images again with naming from 0 to 11424 and it worked..